# Android Studio terminal doesn't recognize gradle as a command

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have Android Studio and its build tool is Gradle.
However, inside the Android Studio Terminal (not the windows cmd..) if i type

```
gradle tasks
```

I get

```
'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How is that possible?
If Android Studio is using gradle then isn't gradle installed already?
to add more confusion, when I look at C:\Program Files I don't see a gradle folder at all.
How does Android Studio and Gradle work together?

thanks

Comment: Use `gradlew` instead, gradle is in hidden folder

Comment: You should read about the gradle wrapper: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Comment: Thanks guys. why commenting and not andwering? i can't give you feedback

Comment: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-is-not-recognized-internal-or-external-command/7468/4

Answer (score 28, accepted):

On Windows you have to use the `gradlew` command (it uses the gradlew.bat in the root project folder).

On Linux and Mac you have to use the `gradle` command.

Comment: For anyone using react-native, gradlew.bat is located in {root project folder}\android

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! But I thought it was the complete oposite: with Windows it was "gradle" and mac or linux it was "./gradlew"